# Using RTTI to determine inheritance graph in C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance, rtti, typeid

What, if any, c++ constructs are there for listing the ancestors of a class at runtime?

Basically, I have a class which stores a pointer to any object, including possibly a primitive type (somewhat like `boost::any`, which I don't want to use because I need to retain ownership of my objects). Internally, this pointer is a `void*`, but the goal of this class is to wrap the `void*` with runtime type-safety. The assignment operator is templated, so at assignment time I take the `typeid()` of the incoming pointer and store it. Then when I cast back later, I can check the `typeid()` of the cast type against the stored `type_info`. If it mismatches, the cast will throw an exception.

But there's a problem: It seems I lose polymorphism. Let's say `B` is a base of `D`. If I store a pointer to `D` in my class, then the stored `type_info` will also be of `D`. Then later on, I might want to retrieve a `B` pointer. If I use my class's method to cast to `B*`, then `typeid(B) == typeid(D)` fails, and the cast raises an exception, even though `D->B` conversion is safe. `Dynamic_cast<>()` doesn't apply here, since I'm operating on a `void*` and not an ancestor of `B` or `D`.

What I would like to be able to do is check `is_ancestor(typeid(B), typeid(D))`. **Is this possible?** (And isn't this what `dynamic_cast<>` is doing behind the scenes?)

If not, then I am thinking of taking a second approach anyway: implement a a class `TypeInfo`, whose derived classes are templated singletons. I can then store whatever information I like in these classes, and then keep pointers to them in my `AnyPointer` class. This would allow me to generate/store the ancestor information at compile time in a more accessible way. So failing option #1 (a built-in way of listing ancestors given only information available at runtime), is there a construct/procedure I can use which will allow the ancestor information to be generated and stored automatically at compile-time, preferably without having to explicitly input that "class `A` derives from `B` and `C`; `C` derives from `D`" etc.? Once I have this, is there a safe way to actually perform that cast?

Comment: I don't know the answer but boost::any seems to manage it. Why not take a look at their code?

Comment: John: As far as I can tell, boost::any actually suffers from the same problem. It also uses `typeid(A) == typeid(B)`; in fact, that's where I got the idea!

Comment: Boost.Any uses a `placeholder` and a `template<class ValueType> holder : placeholder` with pure virtual functions to store the actual type. That's why there solution is able to handle polymorphism.

Comment: @pmr: Boost.Any does *not* seem to handle polymorphism.

Comment: @Matthieu: You are right. Took me a moment to understand what the OP is trying to do and I don't see any way to do it.

Comment: @pmr: Solely exploiting `typeinfo` et virtuality ? Neither do I. Encoding the base classes (somehow) in the derived class, I do, but it gets cumbersome.

Comment: @trbabb: I know this will seem weird, seeing as you just accepted the answer... but *Cassio Neri*'s answer is just spot on *and solves your issue*. He does not use `type_info`, but he does handle polymorphism! You should probably be accepting **his**.

Comment: @MatthieuM. You are right; I did not read through this thread thoroughly enough after noticing that I'd never accepted an answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had a similar problem which I solved through exceptions! I wrote an article about that:

[Part 1](https://web.archive.org/web/20130801021123/https://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/twisting-the-rtti-system-for-safe-dynami/229401004), [Part 2](https://web.archive.org/web/20140710140948/http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/twisting-the-rtti-system-for-safe-dynami/229401004?pgno=2) and [code](https://web.archive.org/web/20150902163658/http://twimgs.com/ddj/images/article/2011/0411/any_ptr.h/any_ptr.h)

Ok. Following Peter's advise the outline of the idea follows. It relies on the fact that if `D` derives from `B` and a pointer to `D` is thrown, then a catch clause expecting a pointer to `B` will be activated.

One can then write a class (in my article I've called it `any_ptr`) whose template constructor accepts a `T*` and stores a copy of it as a `void*`. The class implements a mechanism that statically cast the `void*` to its original type `T*` and throws the result. A catch clause expecting `U*` where `U` = `T` or `U` is a base of `T` will be activated and this strategy is the key to  implementing a test as in the original question.

**EDIT:** *(by Matthieu M. for answers are best self-contained, please refer to Dr Dobbs for the full answer)*

```
class any_ptr {

    void* ptr_;
    void (*thr_)(void*);

    template <typename T>
    static void thrower(void* ptr) { throw static_cast<T*>(ptr); }

public:

    template <typename T>
    any_ptr(T* ptr) : ptr_(ptr), thr_(&thrower<T>) {}

    template <typename U>
    U* cast() const {
        try { thr_(ptr_); }
        catch (U* ptr) { return ptr; }
        catch (...) {}
        return 0;
    }
};
```

Comment: Wow, I wish I had seen this answer sooner. I don't know whether to label this as a stroke of genius or a feat of madness; I guess it's both. I much prefer not involving `shared_ptr` here, and instead making `any_ptr` behave like `unique_ptr` provided the OP uses C++11... but the core mechanism remains striking.

Comment: @Matthieu M.: Thanks for improving my post. I agree that sometimes `unique_ptr` is preferable but at the time I wrote the article `unique_ptr` was neither standardized nor broadly available. The implementation in my code base uses a traits class that allows users to customize the inner smart pointer.

Answer (score 6):

The information is (often) there within the implementation. There's no standard C++ way to access it though, it's not exposed. If you're willing to tie yourself to specific implementations or sets of implementations you can play a dirty game to find the information still.

An example for gcc, using the Itanium ABI is:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <cxxabi.h>
#include <iostream>

bool is_ancestor(const std::type_info& a, const std::type_info& b);

namespace {
  bool walk_tree(const __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info *si, const std::type_info& a) {
    return si->__base_type == &a ? true : is_ancestor(a, *si->__base_type);
  }

  bool walk_tree(const __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info *mi, const std::type_info& a) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < mi->__base_count; ++i) {
      if (is_ancestor(a, *mi->__base_info[i].__base_type))
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}

bool is_ancestor(const std::type_info& a, const std::type_info& b) {
  if (a==b)
    return true;
  const __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info *si = dynamic_cast<const __cxxabiv1::__si_class_type_info*>(&b);
  if (si)
    return walk_tree(si, a);
  const __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info *mi = dynamic_cast<const __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info*>(&b);
  if (mi)
    return walk_tree(mi, a);
  return false;
}

struct foo {};

struct bar : foo {};

struct baz {};

struct crazy : virtual foo, virtual bar, virtual baz {};

int main() {
  std::cout << is_ancestor(typeid(foo), typeid(bar)) << "\n";
  std::cout << is_ancestor(typeid(foo), typeid(baz)) << "\n";
  std::cout << is_ancestor(typeid(foo), typeid(int)) << "\n";
  std::cout << is_ancestor(typeid(foo), typeid(crazy)) << "\n";
}
```

Where I cast the `type_info` to the real type that's used internally and then recursively used that to walk the inheritance tree.

I wouldn't recommend doing this in real code, but as an exercise in implementation details it's not impossible.

Comment: I believe your solution is fine, and probably more efficient than Cassio Neri's one. One could use your approach wherever available, and Cassio Neri's one as a generic (and quite clever!) fallback. Thanks to both of you for your contribution!

Answer (score 4):

First, what you are asking for cannot be implemented *just* on top of `type_info`.

In C++, for a cast to occur from one object to another, you need more than *blindly* assuming a type can be used as another, you also need to adjust the pointer, because of multi-inheritance (compile-time offset) and virtual inheritance (runtime offset).

The *only* way to safely cast a value from a type into another, is to use `static_cast` (works for single or multi-inheritance) and `dynamic_cast` (also works for virtual inheritance and actually checks the runtime values).

Unfortunately, this is actually incompatible with type erasure (the old `template-virtual` incompatibility).

*If you limit* yourself to non-virtual inheritance, I think it should be possible to achieve this by storing the offsets of conversions to various bases in some `Configuration` data (the singletons you are talking about).

For virtual inheritance, I can only think of a map of pairs of `type_info` to a `void* (*caster)(void*)`.

And all this requires enumerating the possible casts manually :(

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible using `std::type_info` since it does not provide a way to query inheritance information or to convert a `std::type_info` object to its corresponding type so that you could do the cast.

If you do have a list of all possible types you need to store in your `any` objects use `boost::variant` and its visitor.

Answer (score 0):

While I can't think of any way to implement option #1, option #2 should be feasible if you can generate a compile-time list of the classes you would like to use. Filter this type list with boost::MPL and the `is_base_of` metafunction to get a list of valid-cast typeids, which can be compared to the saved typeid.